# Normalize CSV data before inserting into SQLite database with Pandas or plain SQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, pandas, csv

Here is a diagram of what I want to accomplish:
[image: Desired data transformation]

The actual CSV files can have tens of thousands or hundreds of thousands of rows per their equivalent of a `Name/Phone` combination, which wastes an enormous amount of memory and disk space. I know how to normalize this data once it is actually in the database using SQL, but I wish to avoid copying all those duplicates in the first place and instead insert a foreign key relation. The disk space consumed by repeated values in these columns is considerable.

Currently I am using Python and Pandas to automate the process of creating a SQLite database and inserting the data into it. I have also tried PostgreSQL for this, though found it slower than pandas+sqlite for some reason.

How do I split this data into multiple tables before inserting into the database?

---

**EDIT** Because of the size of the files, I am processing them in chunks, like this:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3


def read_nlines(file: str, n: int = 10) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.read_csv(file, nrows=n, comment='#', skip_blank_lines=True,
                       sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')


conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

files = glob.glob("data/*.txt")

for file in files:
    data = read_nlines(file)
###--->
###---> This is where I want to transform the data, before writing to sql <---###
###--->
    data.to_sql('table',con=conn,if_exists='replace')

conn.close()
```

Comment: So what's the actual question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pandas`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Joe','Bob','Bob','Bob','Steve','Steve','Steve'],'Phone':['111','222','222','222','333','333','333'],'S1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'S2':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'S3':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
df['ID']=pd.factorize(df['Name'])[0]+1
sql1=df[['ID','S1','S2','S3']]
sql2=df[['ID','Name','Phone']].drop_duplicates()
sql1
Out[729]: 
   ID  S1  S2  S3
0   1   1   1   1
1   2   2   2   2
2   2   3   3   3
3   2   4   4   4
4   3   5   5   5
5   3   6   6   6
6   3   7   7   7
sql2
Out[730]: 
   ID   Name Phone
0   1    Joe   111
1   2    Bob   222
4   3  Steve   333
```

EDIT:

```
ncount=1
for file in files:
    data = read_nlines(file)


    data['ID'] = pd.factorize(data['Name'])[0] + ncount
    ncount+=data['Name'].nunique()
    sql1 = df[['ID', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3']]
    sql2 = df[['ID', 'Name', 'Phone']].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this work across invocations? These files need to be processed in chunks, and I'm wondering how to preserve the results of `factorize` so that running it on different data frames won't reset the indices provided by `factorize`?

Comment: @mooglinux how you proceed chunk here? ,If in for loop , you need adding one more parameter

Comment: A parameter for what? The categories?

Comment: Added to original question.

Comment: @mooglinux check the update:-) you will see the ncount (New parameter )

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to work with whatever data structures you prefer, but this is how it made sense to me.

Load each row in your csv file into a list of two dictionaries. One dictionary for your person-related fields, one for the other fields. You can use the csv library for this - but I imagine if you've gotten this far, you've already got a process in place for this.

Then, create a list of person dictionaries, only adding a dictionary in if it's not in the list.

You can then loop through your original list of lists and add a personKey key to the second dictionary in each of the children lists. Set the key of this list equal to the index of the person dictionary in your list of person dictionaries.

```
dictList = [
    [{'Name': 'Bob', 'Phone': '098-765-4321'}, {'S1': 0.36, 'S2': 0.91, 'S3': 0.24}],
    [{'Name': 'Bob', 'Phone': '098-765-4321'}, {'S1': 0.44, 'S2': 0.36, 'S3': 0.78}],
    [{'Name': 'Steve', 'Phone': '768-098-1234'}, {'S1': 0.55, 'S2': 0.15, 'S3': 0.74}]
]

personRecords = []
numberRecords = []
for item in dictList:
    numberRecord = item[1]
    if item[0] not in personRecords:
        personRecords.append(item[0])
    numberRecord['personKey'] = personRecords.index(item[0])
    numberRecords.append(numberRecord)

for person in personRecords:
    print(person)

for record in numberRecords:
    print(record)
```

You can then take each list of dictionaries, parse them into whatever data structures are needed by your database library, and then upload.